# Golang 1.15.7: Retorno de uma shared library usando *C.char

Tags: golang

Estou tentando criar uma shared library em go, porém o retorno (*C.char) sempre volta vazio:

Como fazer para retornar certo?

```
package main
import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
)
//export Upper
func Upper(palavra *C.char, retorno *C.char, size *int) int {
    fmt.Println(C.GoString(palavra))
    retorno = C.CString(strings.ToUpper(str1))
    *size = int(len(palavra))
    return 0
}
func main() {}
```

Comment: Não deveria ser `**C.char` e então fazer: `*retorno = C.CString(strings.ToUpper(str1))`?

Comment: Inkeliz, testei da forma que você sugeriu, porém apesar de agora eu conseguir um retorno, o retorno esta vindo errado(sujo). Tentei também deixando `*C.char` e colocando `*retorno = *C.CString(strings.ToUpper(str1))`... mas desta forma só altera a primeira posição.